# File Copying in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am Using a Application server for calling Oracle Reports and i have url to call the report when report is called the server convert it into pdf but when report contain large data it got a lot of time to load.I want to do in asp.net that when i call the report url it open the pdf file and copies it into the root of my web folder and next time when i call the url it open the pdf file and on back end loads the

Sir I want to call function on hyerplink in new tab please tell me solution for that

Sir According to My question i want to use multithreading to call one file from root directory and other to download on backend

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();
 client.DownloadFile(Uri, fileName);
```

VB

```
 Dim client As New WebClient
 client.DownloadFile(Uri, fileName)
```

EDIT:

The first argument specify the location of source file. The second argument is a path of destination file. Use `Server.MapPath()` method to get absolute path if you save it at root of web-app.

Markup :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Visible="false" Target="_blank" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
</form>
```

Code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim client As New WebClient
        Dim muri As New Uri("http://your_url")
        Dim destPath = Server.MapPath("~/file.pdf")
        client.DownloadFile(muri, destPath)
        HyperLink1.Visible = True
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/file.pdf"
        HyperLink1.Text = "Open"
    End Sub
```

Comment: what is the uri here and where i write the URL from where i have to download the file

Comment: I also want to copy the download file to my root directory

Comment: One thind dear can i call this method on my hyperlink where i ahev to call the procedure my hyperlink is <a href="http://202.125.144.34:83/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="DownloadFile" >

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" PostBackUrl="~/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf"  runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile" >SAP</asp:LinkButton> This is giving Compiler Error

Comment: Dear there problem in llink button because it is not opening in new window i want to open it in new window

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" OnClientClick="window.open(http://202.125.144.34:83/Files/rwservlet_reptest&report=sap_dashboard.pdf);">Sap</asp:LinkButton> I make this

Comment: @user1099825 I've updated my post. Please update your post instead of adding code in comment section.

Comment: Its Means i cant use hyperlink field to ope new window